# The difference between Present Perfect Simple and Present Perfect Continuous

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-continuous

Why do we **not** say: "I've gardened all day", which would be correct if we have finished gardening but we say: "I've been gardening all day"?  We seem to do the same with other action words: cook, sew, clean, wash, etc.

Comment: 1- Saying "I've gardened all day" does not mean I have finished gardening. 2- What makes you say it is different for other action verbs, can you give examples?

Answer (score 1):

We naturally tend to use Present Perfect Continuous in OP's context partly because it emphasizes the very fact being asserted (that the action has been performed *continuously*).

But more importantly, OP needs to note that there's nothing at all wrong with, for example, *I worked all day*. The main reason we're more likely to say *I've been working all day* is because the Present Perfect form implies a strong connection to the present moment (i.e. - time of speaking). Bear in mind that *I've been doing it all day* doesn't necessarily imply anything about whether you're still doing it - it just implies that if you're *not* still doing it, you only stopped very recently.

Thus you wouldn't normally say *I've been working all morning* in the ***evening***, (unless there's some obvious contextual reason why working continuously several hours ago significantly affects and/or explains your current condition/circumstances).

Comment: I often use the continuous form to show the cause of something in the present: *I've been gardening all day, that's why my hands are dirty.* But I don't consider natural saying *I've garneded all day, that's why my hands are dirty,* do you?

Comment: @Ustanak: In the first place, you've used exactly the same contextual element *(**all day**)* as OP, so naturally the continuous form is likely to be favoured. Second, the verb ***to garden*** is a fairly unusual usage in *any* contexts apart from in the continuous form. Thus, even when given a "leading" question such as *What did you do yesterday?*, native speakers are quite likely to switch the verb form and reply *I was gardening* rather than *I gardened*. But that's a bit "verb-specific* - there's nothing remotely "unidiomatic" about  *I cooked/cleaned [yesterday]*.

Comment: Oh yes, but if I remove *all day*, is still the continuous form favoured?

Comment: @Ustanak: Since that's the *only* "contextualizing context", it's almost meaningless to ask which verb form would be favoured. I imagine *every* verb form will be favoured in some context or another, but if no context is actually specified, what possible use is it to know that, say, [*You're quite right*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%27re+quite+right%2Cyou%27re+quite+wrong&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20%27re%20quite%20right%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20%27re%20quite%20wrong%3B%2Cc0) is more common than *You're quite wrong*?